# Finding my ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have dual booted windows and Ubuntu 12.10 but Windows boot loader takes over grub and I can't boot ubuntu. I tried following instructions here: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) but it requires knowing the partition in which ubuntu is installed.

I booted using a live cd and ran a couple of commands mentioned in that link:

The output of `sudo fdisk -l` is:

```
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 6
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 6
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 6
Warning: invalid flag 0xa9c7 of partition table 6 will be corrected by w(rite)

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe07a620e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      411647      204800    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        10667160   441482264   215407552+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       441482265   594196479    76357107+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4       594198528   625142447    15471960    2  XENIX root
/dev/sda5       441482328   535382189    46949931    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6   ?  3966535220  2853430321  1590931199   98  Unknown

Disk /dev/sdb: 15.6 GB, 15606349824 bytes
116 heads, 52 sectors/track, 5053 cylinders, total 30481152 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        8064    30481151    15236544    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

and the output of `df -Th` is:

```
Filesystem     Type       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow           overlayfs  1.9G  122M  1.8G   7% /
udev           devtmpfs   1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      384M  836K  383M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1      vfat        15G  794M   14G   6% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs   758M  758M     0 100% /rofs
none           tmpfs      4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs      1.9G  1.1M  1.9G   1% /tmp
none           tmpfs      5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none           tmpfs      1.9G  144K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none           tmpfs      100M   32K  100M   1% /run/user
```

I am not sure in which partition(sda1? sda2? sdb1?) is ubuntu installed. It would be great if someone could help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

- Boot ubuntu live cd, and choose `Try Ubuntu`,then connect to the  internet and type the following commands in terminal to install **boot-repair**.

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`
   `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
- Click `Recommended Repair`.

Reboot the pc,you should get the grub menu with access to ubuntu.

Comment: I tried that. It still loads windows 8 boot menu and not grub.

Comment: please upload gparted screenshot on imgur.com and post the link here.

Comment: Here's the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/JLvXLnj.png

Comment: what are the options in the drop down list(located in top right corner of gparted)?

Comment: Two options: `/dev/sda (298 GB)` and `/dev/sdb (14 GB)`

Comment: You doesn't have ubuntu installed on your hard-disk.Normally Ubuntu os was installed in `ext4 filesystem`,but there was no ext4 filesystem,and dev/sdb is your bootable disk.

Comment: But I have been using Ubuntu for more that a year on this system. It was only sometime back when I got the `grub rescue` error and then I used `boot-repair` but then it doesn't show the grub and shows windows 8 boot loader. It should be on the hard-disk!

Comment: it was not in the hard-disk,i'm sure about that.I think you accidentally deleted the ubuntu partition.

Comment: okay...
what will happen if I mount the wrong partition?

Comment: i can't understand your question.

Comment: The top answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows requires to mount the correct partition. I was wondering what'll happen if I mount the wrong partition.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows in this they boot up the live cd,mount the correct `/dev/sda2` ubuntu partition,and by using the `chroot` method they go into the ubuntu installation files and then they update the grub.But you don't have any `ext4 partition`.From the link `dev/sda2` is an ext4 partition.This method works if you mount a ext4 partition.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't start ubuntu 12.04.4 with XP, it was not found. I got my XP, nothing else. I installed grup2win and edited  the grup list. The problem still was there. After consultinng Ease Partition Master I understood, I have my ubuntu on partition 6 (not 2 or 3 or 4...). After editing grup2win again, I got my Ubuntu.